# C#: Retrieve the source of a fired event without the sender object

Tags: c#

I'm using the GMaps.NET Controls and I catch the event "TileLoadComplete":

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMap.NET.WindowsForms/GMapControl/E/OnTileLoadComplete

I create several controls at run-time and all of them share the same function for that event:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl control = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl();
    control.Manager.Mode = AccessMode.ServerOnly;
    control.MapProvider = GMap.NET.MapProviders.GoogleSatelliteMapProvider.Instance;
    control.OnTileLoadComplete += Control_OnTileLoadComplete;
    // set other map properties
}

private void Control_OnTileLoadComplete(long ElapsedMilliseconds)
{
    // who has completed the loading?
}
```

Because there is no sender object in the event signature, I wonder if there is another way to know which control has completed the loading of the map.

Comment: You could try looking at the call stack

Comment: Gosh, there appears to be a variable in your code called `control`.  What's it holding?  I bet if you held onto it in a scope that still exists when the event is fired (whatever that would be, as your question is empty of context), you would have the object you need.  Also, why is gmap.net failing to use the standard event pattern?  They suck.  Tell them.

Comment: @Will thanks for pointing it out. I've update the question. As said I create several hidden "controls" at run-time, but all of them has the same event function. Here I added a for loop, in the application it depends on a user request.

Comment: how about `control.OnTileLoadComplete += m => Control_OnTileLoadComplete(control, m)` then change the handler signature to `Control_OnTileLoadComplete(GMapControl control, long ElapsedMilliseconds)`

Comment: @KMoussa has a very good solution there, which should be added below ASAP.  Whoops.

Answer (score 3):

Would this work?  Use a lambda to capture the sender:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl control = new GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl();
    //...snip...
    control.OnTileLoadComplete += x => Control_OnTileLoadComplete(control, x);
}

private void Control_OnTileLoadComplete(object sender, long ElapsedMilliseconds)
{
    // who has completed the loading?
    // the sender, that's who!
}
```

You'd have to update each usage of `Control_OnTileLoadComplete` to use that lamdba.  You can change the type from `object sender` to `GMapControl sender` if the only 'senders' are of type `GMapControl`.

Comment: Very interesting and powerful approach! I will report back if it works after I understand how to load the map in background. Right now the event never fires because GMapControl doesn't actually load the map if the control is not visible.

Comment: I expect it should work, with the caveat that you won't be able to unregister the event handler because its an anonymous method.

Comment: That means the GC won't automatically dispose the objects because there's still the event handler attached?

Comment: @Mark It means that the object attaching the event will need to live for at least as long as the object the event is subscribed to.  If you weren't planning to unsubscribe the event already then that was happening in the original code anyway, and it just makes the unsubscribing code more tedious, not impossible.